# Bootstrap site doesnt work on other host?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I made a website based on Boostrap: ####

Strange thing when i move it to another host, some things display differently, like the menu doesnt display well and the slider doesnt work: ####

Any idea what the problem can be? Problably something small, but i dont see it :s

Comment: Check your browser console if there is any error

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

I dont get why these errors are not on the other website

Comment: ok, i uploaded the original "vendor" map and now it works. For some reason weird things happen when i just open a bootstrap.min file or something

Answer (score 0):

ok, i uploaded the original "vendor" map and now it works. For some reason weird things happen when i just open a bootstrap.min file or something